# Applying sum / mean / etc. to a list

Tags: r

In R why can I apply mean / sum / etc. to a 1-D vector but not a 1-D list? How can I perform such operations on a list?

Examples:

```
> myvector <- c(1,2,3,4)
> myvector
[1] 1 2 3 4
> sum(myvector)
[1] 10

> mylist <- list(1,2,3,4)
> mylist
[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
[1] 2

[[3]]
[1] 3

[[4]]
[1] 4
> sum(mylist)
Error in sum(mylist) : invalid 'type' (list) of argument
```

Comment: Do you mean how to convert a list to a vector, i.e., `sum(unlist(mylist))`?

Comment: `Reduce('+', mylist)` will work

Comment: @Frank, that's a single function. You could also suggest `do.call(sum, mylist)`, but it won't work the same way with other functions.

Comment: @AnandaMahto +1 to you.  I did not take the time to process the question thoroughly.

Comment: Why would you want that? In your example, a numeric vector is clearly the more appropriate data structure for the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the best option is to use `unlist` to reduce the list to a vector, and then call the function. I created the following wrapper function that does this:

```
call_function_on_list = function(func, l) {
    func(unlist(l))
}
l = c(1,2,3,4)
call_function_on_list(mean, l)
# [1] 2.5
call_function_on_list(sd, l)
# [1] 1.290994
call_function_on_list(sum, l)
#  [1] 10
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm a Java/C++ programmer, and it astounds me that you cannot apply the same function on different containers like you can with Java collections or C++ STL. Each container should have generic iterators so that the functions like sum() can just iterate over the items in the container.

Comment: A list is a container that can contain any R object, nested in any way possible. Unlike C++/Java, a list container does not contain a list of identical objects. Therefore only in a very small subset in the potential uses of `list` would a `sum` even make sense. What would a `sum` be of a vector of numbers and an `lm` object. So, I find the lack of generality logical in this case.